# Workaround for promoting to production when JavaScript bundle has staging env embeded

Tags: javascript, heroku

I'd like to promote staging to production, which copies the slug that was built for staging over to production. Currently this isn't feasible for me because environment variables are embeded into the JavaScript bundle at build time.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: you can split all the environment variables into separate file, and rewrite it once you need with additional step in your CI prod config.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal situation is for environment variables to be available at runtime. That allows you to make changes to the environment without needing to trigger a re-build. This can be achieved by writing them out to a script tag in the HTML document and making them available on the window object.

One situation where having environment variables inside JavaScript files would be advantageous is for wrapping development code e.g. console warnings. If your minifier/bundler performs tree shaking this is a good way of eliminating any development code in production environments, and vice versa.